# Is there a way to send data from InfluxDB to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, influxdb, kafka-producer-api

Is there a way to send data from influxDB to kafka? Also, the kafka topic has an avro schema defined. So I wanted to know if there was a way to send data into kafka from InfluxDB keeping this in mind as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be a few options for this:

- [Telegraf daemon by Influx](https://www.influxdata.com/using-telegraf-to-send-metrics-to-influxdb-and-kafka/) there is also an [Output plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf#supported-outputs).
- [Kafka consumer for InfluxDB](https://github.com/mre/kafka-influxdb) (written in Python)

You could also write your own using the [InfluxDB API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/concepts/api/).

Comment: @EIHaix Kafka consumer for InfluxDB is from kafka to InfluxDB, not from InfluxDB to Kafka.

Comment: Kafka Connect InfluxDB Source connector - https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-influxdb/current/influx-db-source-connector/index.html

Comment: @AminSaqi isn't that solution ultimately tied into being a confluent customer?